# KDF aftertaste?

Tags: water

I have moderate sediment and iron in my 145' well here on my property.

I used to be OK with just a pitcher filter but we were in that direct CAT 5 hit on Panama City, (Fl) a few years back and well the plumbing is old and it MOVED.

So I put in a two-by-10" 3/8's input full cart sized system I had here, took the useless line from the icemaker to it and after letting it run clear for a good 20-30 minutes plugged it in. I have activated carbon on the inlet side and a KDF media filter on the exit side.

I may just be being picky but I seem to get a sort of aftertaste from the thing. I put a brand new dedicated faucet in the sprayer hole too with all new lines but the icemaker feed.

The animals don't like the water either.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Quick & Cheap:**

Swap the order of the filters, or add an additional carbon post-filter. Indeed, when I look up the KDF type of filter it's suggested to be used before carbon filters. There's no suggestion to carbon-pre-filter on any site I've looked at. Sediment suggests one or two mechanical prefilters for particulates in any case.

**Not as quick and more expensive:**

Have both filtered and unfiltered water tested to see what you have in there, if it's harmful or merely unpleasant, and whether it's passing through or being added by the filter.

"The animals don't like it either" would have me going for the full test, as it happens. Importing known-good water until you have test results would also be indicated.

Comment: Have to agree with Ecnerwal...very important to get the water tested.  An RO (reverse osmosis) device could, maybe deal with it.   All depends upon testing.

Answer (score 10):

You really need to have a comprehensive water analysis done to know what you are dealing with. The local health department may do it for free.  It is concerning that the animals don't like the water. They usually know good from bad water.

Comment: thanks everybody, I have been working toward going for testing but want to get as much out FIRST before I do. I know better about the carbon but have pretty high sediment and was trying to kill to birds with....
I have been running the thing five minutes a morning and the taste has dropped considerably, I should have said that the unfiltered main doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: Only two casing unit so carbon as protection to more expensive KDF.